# Certbot Ubuntu 20 apache generating the wrong domain name for certificate

Tags: wordpress, ssl, dns, apache2

I used the Linode MarketplaCE to deploy wordpress. when I run 'certbot --apache' it tries to renew for the '45-33-24-22.ip.linodeusercontent.com' domain name. I need to generate a cert for my domain specifically 'dolohan.live' how can I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

The same is mentioned in Linode's own WordPress installation article. Please take a look [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/products/tools/marketplace/guides/wordpress/):

[image: linode wordpress install guide from linode marketplace]

Here's their own [full guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/enabling-https-using-certbot-with-apache-on-ubuntu/) on how to Install it correctly.

I suspect you needed to provide a domain during the installation of WordPress in order to get an SSL certificate directly on it and not rDNS.

I hope this helps.